# Increasing battery mAh

Tags: batteries, amplifier, parallel, 12v, series

I am looking into setting up a battery pack to keep a device on for an extended period of time (6 Weeks). Research suggests that a battery's voltage and Amps per hour (Ah) can be increased by setting battery's up in Series and Parallel.

If I require a 12V source and to increase Ah will a parallel configuration do so? If so and I have multiple 12V batteries in parallel, my voltage would remain as 12V right?

Look forward to your answers :)

Comment: Yes. Consider a battery of 3.7v(nominal) and capacity 3000mAh. If you connect say 'N' such batteries in series then the voltage of the entire pack will be (N * 3.7) and capacity will remain the same at 3000mAh. But if you connect them in parallel then the voltage of the pack will remain at 3.7v and capacity will be (N * 3000)mAh.

Comment: Understood, thanks for that :). Is there any precautions I should take when doing so?

Anything that may potentially damage the device I will be powering other than short circuiting?

Comment: Read the datasheet of the components involved in your circuit make sure they are not supplied with greater voltage then they are rated.

Comment: Bear in mind whether you want constant(ish) volts at the load, or can handle a variable voltage. Lead (2v) and Nickel (1.2v) keep a moderately constant terminal voltage for most of their discharge, lithium has a significantly variable output voltage during its discharge (4.2v down to 3 or 2.something volts)

Comment: No cruelty intended, but since you don't seem to know what you're doing, why not just buy an already put together 12 volt 100 ampere-hour battery in whatever chemistry you need instead of subjecting yourself/your customer to the pitfalls of DIY?

Comment: I have been asked to put forward options instead of having a singular battery, the help has been greatly appreciated and I have enough information now for me to present a case; my opinion of which is more suitable is the 12V 100Ah battery. Just had to explore options :)

Comment: Note that the IS no "single battery" solution OR **every** solution is a single battery one. A battery = a number of cells. Lead acid 12V comes as 6 c ~~~= 2V cells in a single housing, usually with no access to intercell connections. LiFePO4 (my chouse without more being known) CAN come as 4 x 3V cells in a single housing - appears just like lead acid - or separate cells joined with access to connections or ... .

Comment: No, "Ah" does not stand for "Amps per hour".  No point reading futher.  -1 for the sloppiness, and moving on to something more productive.

Answer (score 2):

From the comment I understood that you are discussing LIPO batteries. The Ah of a battery pack can be increased if batteries are in parallel. The voltage is increased if you put them in series.

When you intend to do this then there is a warning involved. The complete battery pack with LIPO's must be controlled with a balancer. Only individual cells should be put in parallel and then with the following limitation.

1. They should be of the same brand
2. They should have the same age
3. They should have the same capacity
4. They should have the same type

This all is required to ensure that the balancer is capable of monitoring the charging procedure. If not you could run into (dangerous) trouble. due to overcharging of one or more cells.

The charger itself must be a LIPO charger with CC/CV and a time limit on CV.

Comment: Okay thanks, I hadn't considered LIPO, I need to make up  battery that will allow for 100Ah at 12V as the device will need to last 6 weeks.

Comment: 6 weeks is a long time. Test it first. Get enough batteries that it should work for 5 days. Then verify it actually does. If it passes then scale up as planned. If not, then this lets you investigate what else needs to be done. 2ndly, when doing a load=>expectation include an additional 1 or 2 if possible. (balancing weight, cost, etc may not allow over provisioning)

Comment: Where is the downvote comming from and what is the reason. I appreciate an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without more information than we have now, my choice would be a 4 cell Lithium ferrophosphate (LiFePO4) battery. This may not be the best choice - depending on as yet unknown specifications - but has a very good chance of meeting most as yet unknown needs. Smaller and lighter and more costly than lead acid. Slightly larger than LiIon. Excellent temperature range, close to flat discharge voltage curve. Spill proof, orientation agnostic, reliable and well behaved in the event of extreme provocation. (A stake through the heart causes death but not spectacular conflagration).

You can buy eg LiFePO4 100 Ah 4-cell batteries that have Vout > 12V across whole discharge range. Cost is higher than a cheap 12V lead acid 100 Ah battery, but if used multiple times cost may be less and if used many times is lower.

Example LiFePO4 cells - NO endorsement of any brands intended

[100 Ah cells](https://www.ev-power.eu/Sinopoly-40Ah-300Ah/SP-LFP100AHA-Lithium-Cell-LiFePO4-3-2V-100Ah.html) $115 ea

[100 Ah - claim UL certified](http://www.electriccarpartscompany.com/FBC-br-100Ah-3C-32V-br-LiFePo4-Lithium-Prismatic-EV-Battery-br-60-275-825-in-150-69-207-mm-br-772-Lb-35-Kg_p_41.html) $112.
[Same people and brand 100 Ah different model dearer- why?](http://www.electriccarpartscompany.com/100Ah-CALB-UL-Certified-Batteries)

[image]

[LiFeYPO4 100 Ah](https://www.ev-power.eu/Winston-40Ah-200Ah/WB-LYP100AHA-LiFeYPO4-3-2V-100Ah.html) $140 ea. I'm wary of these - perhaps wrongly so.

[LiFePO4 12V 100 Ah](http://www.batteryspace.com/lifepo4-prismatic-battery-12-8v-100ah-1-28-kwh-10c-rate---un38-3-passed-3-2vx4-dgr.aspx) $615

[$NZ pricing but gives a good idea of range](http://www.aasolar.co.nz/AA%20Solar%20Prices.html#Batteries)  LiFePO4 towards bottom of page.

[Ali Express - many sellers](https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-lifepo4-battery-100ah.html) - Caveat Emptor !!!!. Some good and some real bargains. Others ... .

[And more](https://www.alibaba.com/showroom/12v-100ah-lifepo4-battery-pack.html) - love the "deep circle" ones :-).

[Many many many sources !!!](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=lifepo4+100ah&num=100&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPvYry2-vPAhVL-2MKHe_oC5QQsAQIIQ&biw=1680&bih=871)

---

To be sure your result is a good one you must specify your requirement much more tightly.  The requirement does not **appear** very stringent - 100 Ah / 6 weeks = 100 mA average. You need substantial capacity but the average 100 mA drain from a 100 Ah battery "looks easy".

However, what you have NOT told us may make things more difficult. Whether it does is uncertain as you have not told us all the things that may change the difficulty.

You REALLY need to provide details re

- What the load is
- What voltage you REALLY need, and
  what voltage range you can tolerate
- Current variations with time (steady or pulsed (10A, 100A, ...?)
- Environment (temperature, vibration, shock).

  - Low temperature can have a major affect on capacity - if temperature is ever below say 10 degrees Celsius great care is needed. High temperatures are also relevant.
- One off use or repeated?
- One unit or a few or manufacturing volume?
- How important is cost, weight, size, spill-proofness or sealing, generation of toxic or explosive gases, orientation requirements ?
- How important is risk / reliability? (From essentially almost certain not to fail through "utter meltdown is possible but unlikely".

  - If Boeing and Samsung and Apple and ... choose to use batteries where "utter meltdown" can and does happen, why can you be sure that this will not happen to you? In fact, you can be very confident of having a system where this is almost impossible, but as ever, there are tradeoffs.
- How important is cycle life (1 cycle of 6 weeks or 100 or ...?)
- And more ...

More detail = better or much better answers,
and possibly a project saving insight.

At present you will get a generic answer whereas the specific situation may be different. Usually specific cases are worse than average ones :-(.